# Java Rest how to pass only year LocalDate to controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller, localdate

I've got controller which is responsible for generate year report. But I'm struggling with trying to pass only year from Postman to my controller.

I've tried something like that, but it doesn't work :

```
@PostMapping("/generateYearReport")
public ReportDto generateYearReport(@RequestParam("localDate")
                                        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy") LocalDate localDate) {

    Report report = reportYearService.generateYearReport(localDate.getYear());

    return reportMapper.toDto(report);
}
```

If I'm trying pass month and day as well, then I've got error :

At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query."

Any sugestions how to solve that?

Comment: Can you show the post request you're making?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `LocalDate` object?  All you do is call `getYear` on it which returns an `int`.  You could just have your parameter be an `int`?

Comment: How does the code look when this `Exception` is thrown? Is it the above code or a different version? I can see only one parameter there (which is likely to hold information about month and day anyway).

Comment: @BeUndead I think OP is trying to narrow the report down to a month... But I am not really sure. There is that sentence below the code example saying *If I'm trying pass month and day as well, then I've got error*.

Comment: Problem solved. I had bad syntax in my SQL statement, I couldn't find it during last couple of hours. Now I can pass all object as LocalDate and then just use .getYear(). Thanks guys.